# put Button and text box in parallel

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to put the following button and text box in parallel that the button in the left side and the text box in the right ,I try with span and margin but currently the text box is under the button ,how should I do that>

```
<span>
    <input type="submit" id="Connect"  style="margin-left: 195px; width: 150px;" class="btn  action-but" />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Service, new { @class = "col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Service, new { @style = "width: 700px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Service)
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

Comment: Can you paste a working demo?

Comment: what language is this? `@Html.LabelFor...` - doesn't look like pure html...

Comment: ...think you might be looking for this: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

Comment: @webeno-this is razor ,like html helprs...

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/brtgd) output?

Comment: @Tushar-yes something like this but how do you do it with razor?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand good you want to show something like this:
**[button]** [label text errors]

To do that a easy way is to add in style: **display: inline-block;**

The result, based on your code will be something like this

```cs
<span>
    <input type="submit" id="Connect"  style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 195px; width: 150px;" class="btn  action-but" />
    <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Service, new { @class = "col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Service, new { @style = "width: 700px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Service)
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

You can find in JsFiddle a demo of this: http://jsfiddle.net/pR6Wg/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for vertical form. look at this example [bootstrap vertical form](http://www.bootply.com/7lles6wsZh)

**Razor example**

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Service, new { @class="form-control", @placeholder="Enter email" })
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-left: 195px` of submit button add add it inside `.col-md-2` before the `label`.

and change `<div class="col-md-10">` to `<div class="col-md-8">`

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/brtgd)

CODE

```
<span>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="submit" id="Connect"  style=" width: 150px;" class="btn  action-but" />
      </div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Service, new { @class = "col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Service, new { @style = "width: 700px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Service)
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't use a table? Or you want to do it with div's?

```
<table class="col-md-10">
     <td>
           <tr>
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Service, new { @style = "width: 700px;" })
           </tr> 
     </td>
     <td>
           <tr>
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Service)
           </tr> 
     </td>         
</table>
```

Hope it helps! =)

Comment: Tables shouldn't be used for layout purposes.

Comment: so, for what are they for? He never said for what purpose was needed. I know that the new HTML5 kills all the tables and shows them like evil demons, but for something simply as he wants, it was an option.

Comment: They are for tabular data.  Nothing more, nothing less.